# Libgdx - Animation only plays for 1 second inside if statement

Tags: libgdx

Basically, when the ball hits the top wall. I want it to make some lightning strike animation, but the animation only last around 1 second.

```
if(ball.getY() + ball.getHeight() > topWall.getY()) {

        game.getBatch().draw(animation.getKeyFrame(timepassed, false), ball.getX(), ball.getY() + ball.getHeight(), 0, 0, leftWall.getWidth(), leftWall.getHeight() * -1, 1, 1, 0f);
        LightingStrikeRectArrayList.add(new Rectangle(ball.getX(), Apm.HEIGHT - ball.getY() + ball.getHeight() / 2, topWall.getWidth(), topWall.getHeight()));

            for (Rectangle rect : LightingStrikeRectArrayList) {
                if (rect.overlaps(playerHitbox)) {
                    this.game.setScreen(new GameScreen(this.game));
                }
            }
            
        if(!(LightingStrikeRectArrayList.isEmpty() && animation.isAnimationFinished(timepassed))) {
            LightingStrikeRectArrayList.remove(0);
        }
        ball.reverseDirectionY();
    }
```

Comment: The anomation seems to be drawn only if the ball is still at the top wall, because it's in the if block. Because of the `ball.reverseDirectionY()` I would assume, that the ball moves back down and the animation is not drawn anymore, because the if-block is skipped.

Comment: Yeah, I need it the ball to reverse upon collision since balls bounce on walls.

Comment: Move the lightning drawing code out of the if-block.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you only draw the animation as long as the ball is on the top. When the ball moves back down the animation stops.

If you set a boolean variable that indicates, that the ball was touching the top wall, and draw the animation as long as this flag is set, it will continue to be drawn event if the ball moves back down.

A solution could look similar to this:

```
// create a global variable somewhere in the class, to store the flag
private boolean ballTouchedTopWall = false;

public void processGame() {
    
    //...

    if(ball.getY() + ball.getHeight() > topWall.getY()) {

        // set the flag instead of drawing the animation
        ballTouchedTopWall = true;

        LightingStrikeRectArrayList.add(new Rectangle(ball.getX(), Apm.HEIGHT - ball.getY() + ball.getHeight() / 2, topWall.getWidth(), topWall.getHeight()));

            for (Rectangle rect : LightingStrikeRectArrayList) {
                if (rect.overlaps(playerHitbox)) {
                    this.game.setScreen(new GameScreen(this.game));
                }
            }
            
        if(!(LightingStrikeRectArrayList.isEmpty() && animation.isAnimationFinished(timepassed))) {
            LightingStrikeRectArrayList.remove(0);
        }
        ball.reverseDirectionY();
    }

    if (ballTouchedTopWall) {
        game.getBatch().draw(animation.getKeyFrame(timepassed, false), ball.getX(), ball.getY() + ball.getHeight(), 0, 0, leftWall.getWidth(), leftWall.getHeight() * -1, 1, 1, 0f);
        
        // reset the flag when the animation ends
        if (animation.isAnimationFinished(timepassed)) {
            ballTouchedTopWall = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but only when the ball touches the top wall the first time. After the animation finishes the first time, the consecutive animations will be 1 second. I tried moving all the logic part (besides flag/ball.reverseDirectionY();) into the 2nd if statement, but that doesn't work either

Comment: Maybe you need to reset the `timepassed` variable to 0 when the ball touches the top wall?